# CSS: How to make a Div of text underneath another Div selectable?

Tags: html, css

I have a few empty Divs on a page that are basically empty boxes to help me position some stuff to make a "liquid" website. Now I've got content underneath these Divs but I can't highlight/click on the links because these empty Divs are blocking it. I've got a reason I need to have the empty Divs to be on the top layer so I need a way to "click through" these Divs. What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post live page so we can take a look at it? Also when you say "I need to have the empty Divs to be on the top layer" you mean that you are using z-index on that div or what?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure you described is really important to change the same way, I would have placed a transparent div on top of the main div, with the same dimensions of the links and in the same position, and catch + handle the onlclick events on that div.

Or, catch the onclick event on the div and with some mathematical magic (which framework are you using) decide whether the onclick was on the link position or not.

First solution is simpler.